# @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.5, php-7.0

My local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) has had issues this morning and I've had to repair the git HEAD.

Now, I can use git normally with no errors but I am having to run `composer update --no-scripts` instead of `composer update` due to the following error...

> @php artisan package:discover
>
> PHP Warning:  require(/home/neil/all-websites/my-website/laravel/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/neil/all-websites/my-website/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

There were two PHP warnings but I've shortened the question slightly as they were both the same.

I have no errors in Laravel or apache2 (this is on my local Ubuntu machine). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

When I run `composer update` now I get this error in addition to the others...

> Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script